# $.get function not calling in IE

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I designed an application which works in all browser except in IE,
Actually where i got struck means  i added 2 tabs for example,

```
 public string GetTabs()
    {
         strResult = strResult + "<div class='amc-container'>";
                    strResult = strResult + "<div id='links-div' class='simple-round-div-right'>";
         strResult = strResult + "<div id='tab-link1' class='tab-button-enabled'><a href='javascript:void();' onclick=\"showTab('details-div','Code',this,'" + id + "'," + id.ToString() + "," + status + ");\">Products</a></div>";
         strResult = strResult + "<div id='tab-link2' class='tab-button-disabled'><a href='javascript:void();' onclick=\"showTab('details-div','Code',this,'" + code.Trim() + "'," + id.ToString() + "," + status + ");\">Spares</a></div> </div></div>";       
        return strResult;
    }
```

//Javascript function

```
function showTab(div, dom, obj, tcd, tid,status) {
    $("div.tab-button-enabled").removeClass('tab-button-enabled').addClass('tab-button-disabled');

    $(obj).parent().removeClass('tab-button-disabled').addClass('tab-button-enabled');
    $("#" + div).html('Loading...');

    $.get("/common/get_amcb.aspx", { dm: dom, acd: tcd, aid: tid, domain: obj.firstChild.nodeValue,status:status },
    function (data) {
        $("#" + div).html(data);
    });
}
```

$.get() function loads page get_amcb.aspx page & get the data from .aspx page through response.Write() method & bind into the div. 


while **page loading I'm calling this function** (GetTabs()) & assigning to label.

All this works in chrome,Firefox but not in IE if I'll use **IE(9.0 version)** then added data is not reflect into the tab if we want to show data means we need close browser & reopen the browser that time added data is showed, WHY its happening & I'm not getting **whats going on behind** please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE loves caching. Clear cache and see. If that is the case, send a timestamp along with the url. So it will be considered a s anew request.

```
var tstmp = new Date();
var uniqueTimeStamp = tstmp.getTime()
$.get("/common/get_amcb.aspx?timestam="+uniqueTimeStamp , { dm: dom, acd: tcd, aid: tid, domain: obj.firstChild.nodeValue,status:status },
    function (data) {
        $("#" + div).html(data);
    });
```